# Wordpress one-page template with dynamic portfolio section

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I've been searching all morning for answers to no avail. I'm building a one page WordPress template. I have a home page which uses a one page template called one-page.php that is brining in all the other pages. Heres the php from that template:

```
<?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );         
        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This code works great. All the sections can use the content-page.php template part, excluding the portfolio section which I would like to use another template part that brings all the portfolio custom post types.

I've tried to add conditional if statements to both the one-page.php and the content-page.php, like this:

```
    <?php if ( is_page( 'portfolio' ) ) : ?>
    //My portfolio custom post type loop is here
    <? endif; ?>
```

But that didn't work either - I think that is because the is_page() function will be checking the current page being displayed which is the Home page. Rather than figuring out what page the query is currently dealing with - but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me understand how I would go about conditionally loading the portfolio section into a separate template part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this checking page slug, which you can get in the loop. If it is "portfolio" (or whatever you saved), load `content-portfolio.php`, otherwise `content-page.php`. Something like this:

```
     if (have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
     if ("portfolio" === $post->post_name) { 
         get_template_part('content', 'portfolio');
     } else {
         get_template_part('content', 'page');
     }
 endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set condition in file

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    if (is_page('portfolio')) {
        get_template_part('content', 'portfolio');
    } else {
        get_template_part('content', 'page');
    }

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

create a template file named `content-portfolio.php` which is copy of `content-page.php` and put the below code in it. if it show 'call' it means your template is working.

**portfolio.php**

```
<?php
echo "portfolio.php";
die('Call');
?>
```